# Problems with 2d plot

Tags: tikz-pgf

> When I compile this code in python, I get the following output, sorted from the greatest to smallest:

[image]

> On the other hand, when I compile it in latex, I get the following reversed output. What's going on? Could you give me a hand?
>
> --I would also like to know how do I put percentage on the axis--

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=0.98\textwidth}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=0.98\textwidth}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}         % multilenguaje

% grid style

\pgfdeclareplotmark{mystar}{
    \node[star,star point ratio=2.25,minimum size=6pt,
    inner sep=0pt,draw=black,solid,fill=red] {};
}

\decimalpoint

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
    
    
    \begin{axis}[
    axis line style={black},
    legend cell align={left},
    legend style={at={(0.45,0.97)}, anchor=north west, draw=black},
    tick align=outside,
    x grid style={dashed,black!60},
    xlabel={Porcentaje de entrenamiento},
    xmajorticks=true,
    xmin=10, xmax=90,
    xtick style={color=black},
    y grid style={dashed,black!60},
    ylabel={RMSE},
    ymajorticks=true,
    ymin=0.90694, ymax=1.08646,
    ytick style={black},
    xtick align=inside,
    ytick align=inside,
    grid = both
    ]
    \addplot [mark =+,line width=1pt,blue, mark size=1.5pt,dashed]
    table {%
90 0.9508
80 0.9361
70 0.9423
60 0.9423
50 0.9439
40 0.9501
30 0.9607
20 0.9699
10 1
};
\addlegendentry{Baseline}
\addplot [mark =pentagon,line width=1pt,black, mark size=1pt]
table {%
90 0.9371
80 0.9242
70 0.937
60 0.9383
50 0.9493
40 0.9649
30 0.9976
20 1.0421
10 1.0783
};
\addlegendentry{Memory}
\addplot [mark =o,line width=1pt,green!80!black, mark size=1pt]
table {%
90 0.927
80 0.9151
70 0.9309
60 0.9364
50 0.945
40 0.9609
30 0.9759
20 0.9868
10 1.0122
};
\addlegendentry{Model}
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The horizontal axis is oriented in opposite order in both cases.

Comment: I don't know how to change what you're pointing out. Maybe I can try with `x dir = reverse`

Comment: Maybe you should ask the question. I don't know TikZ well enough to say how one proceeds.

Comment: Yeah, wel... I tried with `x dir = reverse ` and it worked

Comment: I've learnt something today! ;o)

Comment: Ironic / sarcastic or not... I am glad you did! :)

Comment: Neither – just a knowing smile…

Comment: The question about percentage appears later, separately, and has an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500251/put-percentage-symbol-on-the-x-axis).